# Combining two output layers into single loss function

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I am trying to implement heteroscedastic aleatoric uncertainty in keras. My model has two final layers:

```
# Classification block
x = layers.Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)

# Good old output
linear_output = layers.Dense(units=1, activation="linear", name='linear_output')(x)

# Data-dependent uncertainty outainty
variance_output = layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear', name='variance_output')(x)
```

I would like to combine these outputs into a single loss:

```
loss = K.sum(0.5 * K.exp(-1 * variance_output) * K.square(K.abs(input_label - linear_output)) + 0.5 * variance_output)
```

I managed to make it work with

```
model.add_loss(loss)
```

but unfortunately this creates problem with saving and loading the model. I would like to find another way to implement it so that saving and loading the model works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the errors which you receive after saving/loading the model.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what error you are getting, so I'm shooting a bit blind here, but it sounds like you have a similar issue as I had.

I created a custom loss function that I used during training, and were therefore unable to load the model. These custom objects must be specified like so:
Note the custom_objects

When building model:

```
def myLoss():
    ... some code here
    return loss

model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = myLoss)
```

Then , when loading model: (The function must be defined in both scripts)

```
model = load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'myLoss' : myLoss})
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know if it helped. Thanks for your input !